# Collection View Cell ImageView Not Fitting Screen in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to fit image view to screen.But image view doesn't fitting. I did setting up constraint margins and my content mode aspect fit(I have tried different content modes). Could you help me please???
My StoryBoard,Collection View Implementation,and result:

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtIN8.png)

[Collection View Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF3np.png)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4mzf.png)

Comment: But what is the size of the cell?

Comment: what is cell size and what is imageview size ?

Comment: My cell has same width and height with image view.Image view has 4 constraints(top, bottom,left,right)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting cell size using collectionView sizeForItemAt delegate